# How can I connect to postgres using the IP address of the localhost?

Tags: networking, connection, postgresql, localhost

This is a new installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on OCI. Postgres database has been installed and is running fine. The problem is I am unable to connect to the database using the IP address of the host. Please see the error below.

```
psql -h 135.145.78.113 -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -W
Password:
psql: error: connection to server at "135.145.78.113", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

When localhost is used, it connects as seen below.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -W
Password:
psql (13.7 (Ubuntu 13.7-1.pgdg22.04+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
```

Your support is much appreciated.

Comment: I would assume you need to add that IP address to your hosts.

Comment: hosts file: 127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
127.0.1.1       staging staging ---after update -127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
132.145.78.113 staging --- same error - including local

Comment: Maybe your router needs to forward that port (let it through the filrewall).

Comment: Your ip addresses don't match: `132.145.78.113` - hosts file `135.145.78.113` - original question. Is this the issue?

Comment: This is not the issue. I masked the IP. Just to further add that the instance is in OCI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this applies to you as I haven't got consistant info on the IP config, but it might do.

Judging by the picture following, the internal LAN address of your VM would not be the same as the IP you would use to connect remotely. If you are typing your commands on the VM you should use the internal IP address, or continue to use `localhost`.

[image: OCI Setup Page]

Comment: This worked for me. I was using the public IP rather than the private IP to connect. Thank you.-----lssnadmin@staging:~$ psql -h 0.0.0.0.0 -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -W
Password:
psql (13.7 (Ubuntu 13.7-1.pgdg22.04+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by using the private IP for the host in OCI. I was using the public IP which was resulting in the error.

Using public IP

```
lssnadmin@staging:~$ psql -h 111.111.111.1 -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -W
Password:
psql: error: connection to server at "111.111.111.1", port 5432 failed: No route to host
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Using the private IP

```
lssnadmin@staging:~$ psql -h 10.0.0.90 -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -W
Password:
psql (13.7 (Ubuntu 13.7-1.pgdg22.04+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```